# Get recent photos from the Facebook v2.1+ graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

Facebook's FQL was deprecated after v2.0.  The website I'm working on previously had a "Recent photos" feature that populated recent photos using this FQL:

`var fql = 'SELECT object_id, aid, images, album_object_id, created, modified, position, caption 
FROM photo 
WHERE aid in (SELECT aid, owner FROM album WHERE owner = me()) 
ORDER BY created DESC 
LIMIT 59';`

I'm trying to figure out a comparable way to do that using the graph api.  the `/photos` endpoint is probably what I want, but I can't figure out if it has a valid `order` queryparam.

In postman I've been messing around with this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/10151316456544622/photos?fields=picture,name,source,created_time&limit=20&order=-created_time&debug=all&access_token=CAAL7TZAyo4RUBAOJe4Jgjdt6NZAqcajRghEGdKwraq4X1yZAKjvgXj4xXAZCoyZCkzMO84mTMJ90Vp5CEfJsT1WsoOwif2QZCS00bGqZAVxqmZChMUqKQmNsu2DvZCoY42ZC5fSBAxUuNCqTWg1QZCBZCz5oQx3wcNZCZCPUHOXMu5i5jZCOTGIiPWrAeTlzhFBqkvoZBZAPSJRhlkdxyrKPmpmOqgKrUeD13TdOtKU4ZD`

The `access_token` is of a FB test account, feel free to go nuts.  I'm not getting any debug information.  There doesn't appear to be anything in the docs about how to change the order of photos.

This example url might not be the best. There's only 7ish public photos for this account, but I will potentially be getting recent photos from accounts with 1000s of photos. I don't want to just get all photos and reverse the list. I want to the most recent 20 photos in one call.

Any ideas?  Is there `order` documentation that I've missed?

Comment: You should check the Graph API explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=10151316456544622%2Fphotos%3Ffields%3Dpicture%2Cname%2Csource%2Ccreated_time%2Cbackdated_time%26debug%3Dall%26limit%3D20&version=v2.3&

It looks like ascending order to me. :-/

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to achieve this using the Graph API, but you can use [Real Time Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3) to get notified about changes to the photos of a user.